# selection in CheckboxTableViewer on win7 is not working

Tags: java, eclipse, windows-7, rcp, jface

i try to use an org.eclipse.jface.viewers.CheckboxTableViewer, as a component of a org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardPage. I created it this way:

```
public void createControl(Composite parent) {
    composite = new Composite(parent, SWT.NULL);
    final GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout();
    gridLayout.numColumns = 2;
    composite.setLayout(gridLayout);
    setControl(composite);

    /* CheckboxTableViewer */
    viewer = CheckboxTableViewer.newCheckList(composite, SWT.BORDER);
    final Table table = viewer.getTable();
    GridData data1 = new GridData();
    data1.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
    data1.grabExcessVerticalSpace = true;
    data1.horizontalSpan = 2;
    data1.horizontalAlignment = SWT.FILL;
    data1.verticalAlignment = SWT.FILL;
    table.setLayoutData(data1);
    table.setHeaderVisible(true);
    table.setLinesVisible(true);

    checkboxColumn = new TableColumn(table, SWT.LEFT);
    ...
```

the content of the viewer is inserted dynamically by a contentprovider. Everything works fine on gnome. While testing this on windows 7 (64 and 32 bit also), i am not able to select any entries of that view. Mouseclicks just seems to have no impact on the view.
I added a mouselistener to the table, and the mouseUp-/Down event is fired, selectionChanged and doubleClick on the viewer is not fired. Anyone who can explain this behaviour to me?

thx in advance,

hage

(i already posted this question in the eclipse forum without any response yet: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/250953/ )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add another style flag while creating the *CheckboxTableViewer*: **SWT.FULL_SELECTION**

```
viewer = CheckboxTableViewer.newCheckList(composite, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
```

You can now select rows in the table by a single clicking.